# How to implement a ScrollChanged event within a listbox with parameters using MVVM light

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, mvvm-light

Trying to fire a ScrollChanged-Event via MVVM light.
What i tried:

```
<ListBox UseLayoutRounding ="True" Name ="myListBox" Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionsList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{Binding BackgroundColorButtons}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ScrollChanged">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ScrollChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="grid1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            ...
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

In Constructor:

```
 ScrollChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<ScrollChangedEventArgs>((s) => OnScrollingCommandParameterhandling(s));
```

Commands:

```
public RelayCommand<ScrollChangedEventArgs> ScrollChangedCommand { get; private set; }
private void OnScrollingCommandParameterhandling(ScrollChangedEventArgs s)
{
var offset = s.VerticalOffset;
}
```

Somehow the event is not firing. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I thinks its an attached event. ListBox or others selectors don't expose that event themselves. You need to, probably, subscribe to ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent.